# Entity not saving update value to db

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to increase the count of a value of db by 1 but its not saving into the db for some reason

```
 public void updateLockedOutCount(string email)
 {
        int count = 1;
        tblPortalUser q = portalEntities.tblPortalUsers.Where(w => w.EmailAddress == email).FirstOrDefault();
        q.loginAttempts = q.loginAttempts + count;
        q.isActive = false;
        _dal.portalEntities.Entry(q).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

        _dal.portalEntities.SaveChanges();
        _dal.portalEntities.Entry(q).Reload();
}
```

Portal Entities is just  a property of my context

```
public portalEntities _portalEntities;
    public portalEntities portalEntities
    {
        get
        {
            if (_portalEntities == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    _portalEntities = new portalEntities();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }

            return _portalEntities;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @DavidG that was my first thought but no their is only one user and its pulling back the correct data sorry its legacy code so have to deal with that

Comment: Hmm, setting the EntityState shouldn't be necessary. Entity Framework should take care of that automatically for you. So a question comes into mind. Are you doing Code-First approach or is your entities generated from a database? And are you sure that the `loginAttempts` that you get FROM the database is correct to start with?

Comment: @DavidG could the realod be sending it back to the database at the wrong time ie sending it back the way it was

Comment: @KarlPatrikJohansson gen from database and yes loign attempts is sitting at 0 as it should be and the values of user are correct for that email address

Comment: One thing I see is that you reference `portalEntities` and then save changes on `_dal.portalEntities`, these are different contexts so will not have the same data.

Comment: @DavidG good catch. I missed to notice that too. Since hes updating the entity from a different context, it will obviously not be saved properly when trying to save the second context.

Comment: @DavidG YOU ARE THE KING !!! NOW WORKING

Comment: King David, I can live with that.

Comment: two david helpings each other even better put an answer man so can give you kudos

Comment: @DavidG can i ask a small question obv my first return value out of this method was just false but now cause I have locked out what is my best way of handling this as a return value